# Why is email template not picking up the values of several fields

Tags: email-template

I have set up an html email template and noticed several field's value is not populated. I have done SOQL query on those records and the value for those fields are good. And I have set the field level security for that particular field visible to everyone. The email template line looks like this:

```
DFV Request: {!Ida_Hearing__c.Domestic_and_Family_Violence_Matter_Text__c}
```

And the field is a formula field whose field looks like below:

```
IF(Domestic_and_Family_Violence_Matter__c , 'Yes', 'No')
```

It doesn't seem to me there is any cross object reference in this email template. What can be the reason why it is not displaying?

Comment: Did you try to check the "Send Test and verify merge field" option on email template? Did it work there?

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty No, it doesn't. It is still in development and testing phase so when I see I didn't see the field value populated I have actually meant the email I received from that button.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out.

It seems that even if I spelled everything perfectly right, the email template might still not work. Should always use Merge Field button instead. Then everything works smoothly for me.

But I am not quite sure whether this is a bug?

Comment: I will also verify this at my end. Hope this is not a bug.